# Can't load SASS with create-react-app and Typsecript and NextJS

Tags: reactjs, typescript, sass, next.js

I keep one styles.scss in the root of my project structure.  I have also enabled SASS using next.config.js.  However, I keep receiving this same error.

`'You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type'`

I've looked everywhere for a solution and come up with nothing.  Seems it might be an issue with Next/TS but I am not sure.  Here is my next.config.ts

```
const withTypescript = require('@zeit/next-typescript');
const withSass = require('@zeit/next-sass');

// Add this after your declarations 
module.exports = withTypescript(withSass({
    sassLoaderOptions: {}
}))
```

And package.json

```
  "name": "kb",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/jest": "^24.0.17",
    "@types/node": "^12.7.1",
    "@types/react": "^16.9.1",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.8.5",
    "@zeit/next-css": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-sass": "^1.0.1",
    "@zeit/next-typescript": "^1.1.1",
    "axios": "^0.19.0",
    "css-loader": "^3.2.0",
    "next": "^9.0.3",
    "node-sass": "^4.12.0",
    "react": "^16.9.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
    "react-scripts": "3.1.0",
    "sass-loader": "^7.2.0",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe it's happening because of `next-typescript` in the latest Next.js version typescript is integrated in Next.js https://github.com/zeit/next.js#typescript

Comment: I  have tried it without, and that didn't resolve.

Comment: Can you make a repo with minimal code just take your project and delete most pages and delete most components....

Comment: https://github.com/barictj/nextexpress .  I have commented out the import statement from index.tsx just to get it up and running